# jQuery expandable grid (2 columns)

Tags: jquery

I have a grid =>

[image]

The idea is for the user to click on the boxes, and they would expand with some extra content.

Now, it all works great when you click on the boxes in the left column, but if you click on one of the boxes in the right column - here's what happens (click on the yellow box) =>

[image]

Basically, I'm trying to fix the holes and keep the elements in their initial order.

Here's what I expect should happen when I click on the yellow box (simulated image) =>

[image]

Is there maybe a plugin I could use?

and here's the jsfiddle link => [here](http://goo.gl/UMl3A)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of plugins that may match your purpose:

1. Isotope: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/
2. Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/
3. Nested: http://suprb.com/apps/nested/
4. Freetile: http://yconst.com/web/freetile/
5. vGrid: https://github.com/xlune/jQuery-vGrid-Plugin

I am sure you will find at least some inspiration.

In addition and because you mentioned the importance of ordering, the Masonry Ordered Plugin is interesting: http://masonry-ordered.tasuki.org/

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on `http://jsonenglish.com/projects/flex/`
Let me know your thoughts

Comment: it is similar to what I need (my client needs) but not the perfect solution for this scenario... thanks anyway

Comment: btw: I just added a link to jsfiddle

Comment: Can you explain your problem little bit more

Comment: please take a look at the third image.. there's a hole left after the blue box.. I want the elements to fit into the available spaces while expanding..

Comment: Did you mean if the yellow box expands to 100% blue box also need to expand 100%?

Comment: no.. if the yellow box expands, the blue one should fall under it, the purple one should stack right next to it (leaving no holes) and the orange one would be the single box left in the last row

Comment: sorry - I should've been more clear.. I'll update the answer now with another image